# How can I pass same data to multiple views in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, qweb

I have some data that I need to pass to every website views in Odoo. The problem is that I don't know the proper way to do that. I have thought about manually add them to every render method, but it doesn't feel right for me. And it violated DRY, of course.

I am using Odoo 12. Thank for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

every page of odoo call website.layout template (for header & footer) so you can place your data in layout template and it will available in every page